# JMeter - Execute HTTP Request until Response Headers matches

Tags: jmeter, request, jmeter-5.0

I'm new with JMeter and I'm working with a script for checking the cache, the scenario was to:

1. do a GET request
2. verify that it has been cached
3. do a DELETE request
4. verify that the cache has been deleted

However since there are three instances in the environment I'm working on my script is having intermittent failures because of the different `x-internal-service-host` being returned.

My test results looks like this:

1. do a GET request (x-internal-service-host returned is
   c3c8021a51a9:8080 - PASS)
2. verify that it has been cached
   (x-internal-service-host returned is 4eb7ac9d4a76:8080 - FAILED
   because the call made was for c3c8021a51a9:8080)
3. do a DELETE
   request (x-internal-service-host returned
   is c3c8021a51a9:8080 - PASS)
4. verify that the cache has been deleted
   (request x-internal-service-host returned is  c3c8021a51a9:8080 -
   FAILED because the delete was made for 4eb7ac9d4a76:8080)

I'm thinking of extracting the Response Header `x-internal-service-host` in step 1 but I'm not sure how to proceed once extracted, is it possible to send a GET request until the Response Header extracted matches the Response Header result for steps 2 to 4 or is there a better way to do this?